# How can I know if Cygnus is connected to Cosmos correctly?

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus, fiware-cosmos, cosmos

I have *Cygnus* instance configured. I'm publishing information through *Orion Context Broker*, but now I want to check if everything is working properly.

How could I ensure that everything is fine?

Comment: This was answered in https://ask.fiware.org/question/435/how-can-i-know-if-cygnus-is-connected-to-cosmos-correctly/

Comment: Where is now the new documentation for Orion Context Broker working correctly with Cygnus and Cosmos?